# Spyder iPython Console error

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, spyder

Could someone help me with decoding this error message for my Spyder console in Python? This likely relates to the fact that whenever I updated my Anaconda package from 3 to 3.5, I saved it in another new folder. After I realized my mistake, I uninstalled and deleted the former Anaconda navigator. The environment it is referring to is one that I created but never really used, so I'm kind of confused why it was selected as the only available environment for my updated version. Here is the error:

```
File "C:\Users\mlt08\Anaconda3_5\envs\cryptocurrency-analysis\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\introspection\manager.py", line 220, in get_completions
    info = self._get_code_info('completions', automatic=automatic)
  File "C:\Users\mlt08\Anaconda3_5\envs\cryptocurrency-analysis\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\introspection\manager.py", line 216, in _get_code_info
    **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mlt08\Anaconda3_5\envs\cryptocurrency-analysis\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\introspection\utils.py", line 75, in __init__
    self._get_info()
  File "C:\Users\mlt08\Anaconda3_5\envs\cryptocurrency-analysis\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\introspection\utils.py", line 87, in _get_info
    lexer = find_lexer_for_filename(self.filename)
  File "C:\Users\mlt08\Anaconda3_5\envs\cryptocurrency-analysis\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\introspection\utils.py", line 180, in find_lexer_for_filename
    lexer = get_lexer_for_filename(filename)
  File "C:\Users\mlt08\Anaconda3_5\envs\cryptocurrency-analysis\lib\site-packages\pygments\lexers\__init__.py", line 203, in get_lexer_for_filename
    res = find_lexer_class_for_filename(_fn, code)
  File "C:\Users\mlt08\Anaconda3_5\envs\cryptocurrency-analysis\lib\site-packages\pygments\lexers\__init__.py", line 168, in find_lexer_class_for_filename
    for cls in find_plugin_lexers():
  File "C:\Users\mlt08\Anaconda3_5\envs\cryptocurrency-analysis\lib\site-packages\pygments\plugin.py", line 53, in find_plugin_lexers
    yield entrypoint.load()
  File "C:\Users\mlt08\Anaconda3_5\envs\cryptocurrency-analysis\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2404, in load
    self.require(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mlt08\Anaconda3_5\envs\cryptocurrency-analysis\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2427, in require
    items = working_set.resolve(reqs, env, installer, extras=self.extras)
  File "C:\Users\mlt08\Anaconda3_5\envs\cryptocurrency-analysis\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 872, in resolve
    raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict: (parso 0.1.1 (c:\users\mlt08\anaconda3_5\envs\cryptocurrency-analysis\lib\site-packages), Requirement.parse('parso==0.1.0'), {'jedi'})
```

It has a selection to submit to Github but whenever I press it, it just errors out, so I figured this would be the best way to try and get it resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*)

> pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict: (parso 0.1.1 (c:\users\mlt08\anaconda3_5\envs\cryptocurrency-analysis\lib\site-packages), Requirement.parse('parso==0.1.0'), {'jedi'})

The error message is quite clear: you need to downgrade the package called `parso` to its `0.1.0` version. If you are using Anaconda, you need to open a system terminal (i.e. cmd.exe) and run there

`conda install parso=0.1.0`

If that fails or you used pip to install packages in your environment, then you need to run

`pip install parso==0.1.0`

*Note*: For next time, please try to report Spyder errors on Github instead of opening a question here. This exact same error has been reported a lot of times already.